# How to disable required field "company" for customers in Prestashop 1.7.5?

Tags: prestashop, backoffice

i'd like to make Company Field not required in adress form in Back Office -> Customers -> adresses -> click on modify or create adress.

Just looked in AdminAdressesController but don't where to make overriding...

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

There is an option at Back Office -> Customers -> adresses -> Set required field for this section.(At bottom of address list).

Here you can set or unset required fields.